# perform in situ updates in teradata

Tags: teradata

What does it mean to perform `in situ updates` in teradata? I could not find anything via google. Any feedback would be very much appreciated.

PS:

This is an excerpt from a best practice doc I am digesting:

"Update processing of large amounts of data is perhaps the most inefficient operation that is routinely performed on Teradata. In almost all cases it is more efficient to insert the changed rows to another table rather than updating them in situ."

DONT'T: Perform in situ updates or deletes unless unavoidable.

Comment: It's probably an update in place, i.e. the data block is directly updated without assigning a new block.

Comment: Never heard..  "in situ" (latin) generically means "locally,  in place". Maybe a little more context might help us helping you.

Comment: @Insac - see PS

Comment: Ok, in this case *in situ update* simply means *update*. Now this "best practise" is totally wishy-washy, there's no definition of *large amounts*, large Updates are bad (or really bad, see PostgreSQL) in other DBMSes, too. Of course, updates on the PI/partitioning should be avoided, similar for other indexed columns (but one could drop/recreate those indices), but otherwise direct Updates avoid recreating other indexes and re-granting rights.

Comment: @dnoeth I agree with your interpretation ("in situ"="normal update"). Indeed in Teradata I never heard of such a good practise (ok,  apart from the no PI/partitioning update). In Oracle the rationale for such a rule was (but many versions ago) that if the update was substantially changing the size of the row (e.g. a column full of nulls filled with a 50 chars value) the database could need to search space in other blocks leading to long update times and a less efficient physical distribution of data.

Comment: A correction on my last comment about Oracle: it seems that most of the reasons to go for the insert on Oracle,  were due to some optimization (nologging + append hint) that are available for INSERT statement or CTAS, but not for updates.  So the reason is strictly Oracle specific in this case.